# PHP & SQL to get a certain row

Tags: php, sql

Hello i am just starting out and not too bad with HTML but no hardly anything on PHP, I have created a basic PHP code to get data from my sql database but limit to the first 3 and echo them out.
However i would really like to be able to put these in fancy looking divs later on in a different order, so say row 1 in div 1 row 2 in div 2 etc.
I know how to select and echo line based on a unique id but i want to be able to say query by date order then limit to 3 and echo those in different divs on the website.
Ive looked everywhere so any help would be very good, here is my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbc_posts ORDER BY ID ASC limit 3");

$unique_id = 'unique_id';

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

echo  $rows[type] . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo '<div>' . $rows['type'] . '</div>';`, basically.  you already have all of the basics in place. you should be looking at NOT using the mysql_*() functions anymore - that library is obsolete and removed from newer php versions. use mysqli (note the `i`) or PDO instead.

Comment: Hi Marc Thank you for the advice on mysqli, however this new code works by putting in 3 divs, but what i am trying to achieve is say only show result 2, so for example in the database under type i had Red,Blue,Yellow returned from my query with limit 3 and i wanted to only echo line 2 so only Blue would be in the Div? ( i know im not making myself very clear!)

Comment: Yes, you're not very clear. Maybe the query should have `WHERE type='Blue'`? Or the loop should have `if ($rows['type'] == 'Blue')`?

Comment: sorry il have another attempt and trying to explain, its basically for a section on the front page that will show the latest 3 products uploaded to the database but there will be lots of other things between them so want to be able to say just echo the latest then in another seperate div say the 3rd latest ,so i wont actually know the type will be say blue, i do appreciate the help

Comment: Put them in an array in the fetch loop. Then put `$array[0]` in the latest DIV, and `$array[2]` in the third-latest DIV.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to do the trick!